# Kth Smallest Element in a BST Optimized Solution

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I was going through this leetcode problem.

https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-smallest-element-in-a-bst/description/

1. One solution is to do an inorder traversal. Navigate through it and find the kth smallest.
   https://www.programcreek.com/2014/07/leetcode-kth-smallest-element-in-a-bst-java/
2. The other solution I came across is where we pass in a int[]{poss,val} and recursively

[image]

However none of this resolve the follow up

**What if the BST is modified (insert/delete operations) often and you need to find the kth smallest frequently? How would you optimize the kthSmallest routine?**

anyone has any implementation handling this issue. I did see an incomplete example of using custom TreeNode with count but does not fit in since the TreeNode is being passed in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find kth smallest element in a BST when the tree may be modified frequently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77094973/how-to-find-kth-smallest-element-in-a-bst-when-the-tree-may-be-modified-frequent)

Answer (score 0):

[What changes when implementing lazy deletion into a binary search tree exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613422/what-changes-when-implementing-lazy-deletion-into-a-binary-search-tree-exactly)
Lazy deletion is an option. What this is that you basically have a boolean flag value for each node indicating whether it is deleted or not(but not actually modify structure at all.)