# How to find kth smallest element in a BST when the tree may be modified frequently?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm working the problem [LeetCode 230: Kth Smallest Element in a BST](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-smallest-element-in-a-bst). My Python code uses recursive inorder traversal, and although it is not directly relevant to this question, is given below for reference. In the worst case, it takes linear time (`O(n)`) if we end up visiting all the nodes (`k = n`).

```
def kth_smallest(root: Optional[TreeNode], k: int) -> int:
    def dfs(node: TreeNode, count: int) -> tuple[int, int]:
        """
        :param node: Current node
        :param count: Number of nodes visited so far
        :returns: a 2-tuple consisting of the number of nodes visited, and the value of the last visited node.
            If the kth node is found, immediately returns the value of the kth node
        """
        if node.left is not None:
            # count is the number of nodes in the left subtree.
            count, val = dfs(node.left, count)
            if count == k:
                return k, val
        # count the current node.
        count += 1
        if count == k or node.right is None:
            return count, node.val
        return dfs(node.right, count)

    assert root is not None
    return dfs(root, 0)[1]
```

There is a follow up question that asks:

> If the BST is modified often (i.e., we can do insert and delete operations) and you need to find the kth smallest frequently, how would you optimize?

I'm thinking [B+ Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree). Find/Insert/Delete operations run in `O(log n)` time. A range query with `k` elements occurring within the range requires `O(k + log n)` time.

But can we find the k-th smallest element in a B+ tree any faster than `O(n)`? Note that I mention B+ tree here in reference to my comment "*I'm thinking B+ tree*". Another data structure that fits the problem description, but is not mentioned in the question, would work just fine.

Comment: One can augment a BST into an [order statistic tree](//en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree). (For this to be of advantage, "rank/order queries" need to be somewhat frequent, too.)

Comment: @greybeard I think the BST needs to be balanced, otherwise, the other operations will suffer. So, I guess, a B tree with size of each subtree stored at each node should provide O(log n) for all operations.

Comment: *"can we find the k-th smallest element in a B+ tree any faster than O(n)"*: A B+tree and BST are different structures, and the LeetCode framework has provided the class definition of a BST nodes, and asks when a *"BST is modified often"*, so I don't think the intention there is to switch to a different data structure, like a B+tree. In short: is your question really this last line of your post?

Comment: @trincot “_is your question really this last line of your post_” Yes it is, but if I didn’t set the context, my question would be downvoted and closed in no time. As for your comment, I don’t think the follow-up necessarily limits or imposes any particular structure. The Node structure you saw was for the original question there.

Comment: Sure, but it still says *"If the BST is modified often"*. Not *"if your chosen data structure is modified often"*. But OK, I get you don't want an answer that is about BST, but about B+tree. But then you really need to change the title of your question.

Comment: @trincot I want an answer to my question, and don't care whatever B* tree it uses. If I had a preference, I'd not be asking this question in the first place :)

Comment: Sorry to insist, but you ask *"But can we find the k-th smallest element in a B+ tree any faster than O(n)?"*. That is quite specific to B+tree, not any data structure? Reading your comment I'm now not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Fair point, please see my update. Hopefully, that resolves the confusion.

Comment: Alright, that clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with B+tree, B-tree, AVL, Red-Black, Skip List, or another efficient *sorted* container of your choice.

The idea is to extend nodes with a `size` attribute so you can greedily decide how to navigate down the structure to the k<sup>th</sup> value.

As you started out with a BST, you can turn your BST into an AVL tree (augmenting nodes with a balance factor attribute) and turn it into an order statistic tree (augmenting nodes with a size attribute).

Contrary to how LeetCode presents their BST, it is good practice to store the root in a separate class so that you can define insert/delete methods on it and support the concept of an empty tree.

That second class could look like this:

```py
class AugmentedAvl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, value):
        self.root = AugmentedAvlNode.insert(self.root, value)

    def delete(self, value):
        self.root = AugmentedAvlNode.delete(self.root, value)

    def kth_smallest(self, k):
        if self.root and self.root.size >= k:
            return self.root.kth_smallest(k)
    
    def size(self):
        return AugmentedAvlNode.sizeof(self.root)
```

The augmented Node class would have most of the logic:

```py
class AugmentedAvlNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.children = [None, None]  # Can access through left,right getters/setters
        self.bf = 0  # Balance factor should be -1, 0 or 1.
        self.size = 1  # Number of nodes in the tree rooted by this node
        
    @property
    def left(self):
        return self.children[0]
    
    @left.setter
    def left(self, value):
        self.children[0] = value    

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self.children[1]
    
    @right.setter
    def right(self, value):
        self.children[1] = value    

    @staticmethod
    def sizeof(node):
        return node.size if node else 0

    def min(self):
        return self.left.min() if self.left else self.val

    def attach(self, side, child):  # Does not take care of balance factors
        self.children[side] = child
        self.size = sum(map(self.sizeof, self.children)) + 1
        return self

    def adjust_balance(self, add_bf):
        if self.bf != add_bf: # The balance factor update will stay in range
            self.bf += add_bf
            return self
        # Imbalance would occur. Prepare for rotation:
        side = (1 - self.bf) // 2
        lifting = self.children[1-side]
        if lifting.bf == -self.bf:  # Inner grandchild is heavy: start double rotation
            child, lifting = lifting, lifting.children[side]
            self.bf, child.bf = (+(lifting.bf < 0), -(lifting.bf > 0))[::-self.bf]
            lifting.bf = 0
            lifting.children[1-side] = child.attach(side, lifting.children[1-side])
        else: # Prepare simple rotation:
            self.bf *= not lifting.bf
            lifting.bf = -self.bf
        # Finish rotation
        return lifting.attach(side, self.attach(1-side, lifting.children[side]))

    @classmethod
    def insert(cls, node, value):
        if not node:  # Found the spot where to insert
            return cls(value)
        if node.val == value:
            raise ValueError("insert({value}): tree already has this value")
        side = value >= node.val
        child = node.children[side]
        orig_bf = child and child.bf
        node.children[side] = cls.insert(child, value)
        node.size += 1
        if child and (orig_bf or child.bf == 0): # Height didn't change
            return node
        return node.adjust_balance((-1, 1)[side])

    @classmethod
    def delete(cls, node, value):
        if not node:
            raise ValueError("delete({value}): value not found in tree")
        if node.val == value:  # Found the node to delete
            if not node.left or not node.right:  # Simple case
                return node.left or node.right
            value = node.val = node.right.min()  # Delete successor node instead
        side = value >= node.val
        child = node.children[side]
        orig_bf = child and child.bf        
        child = node.children[side] = cls.delete(child, value)
        node.size -= 1
        if child and (child.bf or orig_bf == 0): # Height didn't change
            return node
        return node.adjust_balance((1, -1)[side])
              
    def kth_smallest(self, k):
        left_size = self.sizeof(self.left)
        if k <= left_size:
            return self.left.kth_smallest(k)
        k -= left_size + 1
        if k == 0:
            return self.val
        return self.right.kth_smallest(k)
```

Here is code that tests the above implementation:

```py
class TestableAvl(AugmentedAvl):
    def inorder(self, node=None):
        node = node or self.root
        if node:
            if node.left:
                yield from self.inorder(node.left)
            yield node.val
            if node.right:
                yield from self.inorder(node.right)
    
    def verify(self):
        # inorder sequence must be sorted
        values = list(self.inorder())
        if values != sorted(values):
            raise ValueError(f"Tree does not have a correct inorder sequence {values}")
        self.verify_node(self.root)

    def verify_node(self, node):
        # balance factors and sizes must be correct
        if not node:
            return -1, 0  # height, size
        left_height, left_size = self.verify_node(node.left)
        right_height, right_size = self.verify_node(node.right) 
        height = max(left_height, right_height) + 1
        bf = right_height - left_height
        size = 1 + left_size + right_size
        if node.size != size:
            ValueError("Size inconsistent at node {self.val}")
        if node.bf != bf or abs(bf) > 1:
            ValueError("Balance factor inconsistent at node {self.val}")
        return height, size


from random import shuffle

def main():
    for i in range(30):
        print(f"Running random test {i}")
        lst = list(range(130))
        shuffle(lst)
        tree = TestableAvl()
        for value in lst:
            tree.insert(value)
            tree.verify()
        if tree.size() != len(lst):
            raise ValueError("Tree does not have the expected size")
        for k in lst:
            if tree.kth_smallest(k + 1) != k:
                raise ValueError("kth_smallest({k}) returns wrong value")
        shuffle(lst)
        for value in lst:
            tree.delete(value)
            tree.verify()
    print("done")

main()
```

#### Other solutions

There are of course libraries that can offer this functionality. There is [SortedList](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html), part of [SortedContainers](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/), which implements `__getitem__`, so you can get the k<sup>th</sup> element with `lst[k-1]` syntax.

See also: [Is there a module for balanced binary tree in Python's standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2298165/5459839)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Although I’ve not critically studied the code line-by-line (and no one would be able to come up with this during an interview, which is what LeetCode exists for), the general idea makes sense and is consistent with what’s been discussed so far in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

AVL tree/Red-Black tree with the size of the subtree stored at each node provides `O(log n)` for all operations.
This turns the tree into an Order statistic tree.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree

https://www.baeldung.com/cs/red-black-tree-vs-avl-tree

Answer (score -1):

You can use the augmented BST, in order to achieve this, I have added only for insertion, you can add delete as well, no major difference, just reduce the size and add delete node function

```
 class Node {
    int val;
    int size;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    public Node(int val){
        this.val = val;
        this.size = 0;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
class Aug{
    
    Node root;

    public Aug(){
        this.root = null;
    }
    public void insert(int key){
        this.root = insertInAug(this.root, key);
    }
    public Node insertInAug(Node root, int key){
        
        if(root == null) return new Node(key);

        if(key > root.val){
            root.right = insertInAug(root.right, key);
        }else{
            root.left = insertInAug(root.left, key);
        }
        root.size++;
        return root;
    }

    public int kthSmallestInAug(int k){
        return getKth(this.root, k);
    }
    
    public int getKth(Node root, int k){

        //base case
        if(root == null) return -1;
        int leftSize = (root.left == null) ? 0 : root.left.size;

        if(k == leftSize+1){
            return root.val;
        }else if( k < leftSize+1){
            return getKth(root.left, k);
        }else{
            return getKth(root.right, k-(leftSize+1));
                        //if Kth element lies in right side, then you have to reduce the k,
                        // why to reduce k? if 7th smallest element we need to find
                        // if we have 5 element in left side then we have to find 2 element in right side
                        //coz in next interation we are going to deepest left and move upward, on that point we need right k(k-leftside element)
                        //meaning we need to find 2 element from deepest left
        }
        
    }

}
class Solution {
    public int kthSmallest(TreeNode root, int k) {
        Aug aug = new Aug();
        inOrder(root, aug);
        return aug.kthSmallestInAug(k);
    }

    public void inOrder(TreeNode root, Aug aug){
        if(root == null) return;
        inOrder(root.left, aug);
        aug.insert(root.val);
        inOrder(root.right, aug);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything beyond what the existing answers cover.